Windows with external hard drive in enclosure
I have a Kesu 2530 and Orico 25PW1 USB3.0 enclosure case. I use Seagate ST500LM030 and WDC WD10JPVX-08JC3T5, APPLE HDD HTS541010A99E662 2.5" hard drives.
In Windows 10 there is an eject function to safely remove hardware. When this function is executed, and the HDD + case does not appear in Windows, for example "E:" even with the USB3.0 cable connected to the PC on/case.
After all this happened, my hand hit the USB3.0 enclosure case and it moved on the table.
Did this hit cause friction between the 2.5" HDD read/write heads and the magnetic platters, scratching them?
image

"Did this hit cause friction between the 2.5" HDD read/write heads and the....", No, but it might have shifted the moon by (about) 1 micrometre.     Or, in other words, what is the relationship between an enclosure case, and scratching ??

Once a mechanical HDD is done reading/writing, it parks the heads on the ramp - so no, highly unlikely. If you're paranoid, you can always install smartmontools, run a long S.M.A.R.T test (usually ~3hrs/TB): smartctl - t long /dev/<drive>, then check the output for errors after it's completed: smartctl -a /dev/<drive>

Do all 2.5" HDDs support head parking after ejecting "safely remove hardware in Windows even if the USB cable remains connected to the enclosure/PC after ejecting in Windows or do only some support it?
Does the model and brand of the USB3.0 enclosure case interfere with the head parking of the 2.5" HDD after ejecting "safely remove hardware in Windows and without disconnecting the USB cable after ejecting?

Please read: Would picking up a sata connected hdd and moving it while the computer is running damage the hdd?

Maybe yes, maybe no... try checking disk and ask again.

not responde my doubts above

2.5" hdd parks or does not park the heads after ejecting safely remove hardware in Windows but keeping the usb3.0 cable from the enclosure case USB3.0 connected to the pc/enclosure after ejection?
or parking some cut power and physical disconnect drive?

Do the model, brand, chip of the USB3.0 enclosure case and Windows power settings have any relation to the parking of the heads of a 2.5" HDD + enclosure usb3.0 after the Windows "safely remove hardware" eject command is completed and the letter E: disappears from the system without disconnect usb cable after eject in windows?
